# Everything points to reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have several domains on the same server i.e IP address, but they all show the reverse proxy.

When I type in `example1.com` and `example2.com`, they both go to the reverse proxy for `someapp.com`

Here's the `nginx.conf` file

```
  # someapp.com
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name someapp.com;
    return 301 https://someapp.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name someapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/someapp.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/someapp.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass 'http://localhost:3000/';
    }

    location /pics/ {
      root /home/user;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }

  # example1.com ######################################

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example1.com;
    location / {
       proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
    }
  }

  # example2.com ######################################

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example2.com;
    root /home/user/example2;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

When I type `example1.com` it goes to `~~https~~://someapp.com`

When I type `http://example1.com` it goes to `example1.com`

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was due to the SSL certificate, meaning both `example1.com` and `example2.com` need their own certificates.